# Sum of time spans

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have table like that

```
Code     Time                    Value       RowNum
-------- ----------------------- ----------- -------
I370902P 2015-12-04 09:00:00.000 5.0         1
I370902P 2015-12-04 09:01:00.000 4.4         2
I370902P 2015-12-04 09:02:00.000 6.0         3
I370902P 2015-12-04 09:03:00.000 7.2         4
I370902P 2015-12-04 09:04:00.000 6.4         5
I370902P 2015-12-04 09:05:00.000 4.5         6
I370902P 2015-12-04 09:06:00.000 4.9         7
I370902P 2015-12-04 09:07:00.000 5.0         8
I370902P 2015-12-04 09:08:00.000 10.1        9
I370902P 2015-12-04 09:10:00.000 7.2         10
I370902P 2015-12-04 09:11:00.000 6.7         11
I370902P 2015-12-04 09:12:00.000 6.6         12
I370902P 2015-12-04 09:13:00.000 7.1         13
I370902P 2015-12-04 09:14:00.000 4.1         14
I370902P 2015-12-04 09:15:00.000 5.2         15
I370902P 2015-12-04 09:16:00.000 7.6         16
I370902P 2015-12-04 09:17:00.000 4.3         17
```

I'm trying to find out for how long the `'Value'` was greater than `N` for each `'Code'`. But time span when `'Value'` exceeded `N` shoul be more than M minutes (in the example - 3 minutes). If there is a gap, and interval before (or/and after) the gap less than `M` minutes it dosen't count.

For example:
for `Code = I370902P`, `N = 5` and `M = 3`  the answer is `7` minutes (rows 3, 4, 5, 10, 11, 12, 13).

```
Code     Time                    Value       RowNum
-------- ----------------------- ----------- -------
I370902P 2015-12-04 09:00:00.000 5.0         1
I370902P 2015-12-04 09:01:00.000 4.4         2
I370902P 2015-12-04 09:02:00.000 6.0         3 --------
I370902P 2015-12-04 09:03:00.000 7.2         4         |-> YES 3 min
I370902P 2015-12-04 09:04:00.000 6.4         5 --------
I370902P 2015-12-04 09:05:00.000 4.5         6
I370902P 2015-12-04 09:06:00.000 4.9         7
I370902P 2015-12-04 09:07:00.000 5.0         8
I370902P 2015-12-04 09:08:00.000 10.1        9 ---------> NO (just 1 minute)
I370902P 2015-12-04 09:10:00.000 7.2         10 --------
I370902P 2015-12-04 09:11:00.000 6.7         11         |
I370902P 2015-12-04 09:12:00.000 6.6         12         |-> YES 4 min
I370902P 2015-12-04 09:13:00.000 7.1         13 --------
I370902P 2015-12-04 09:14:00.000 4.1         14
I370902P 2015-12-04 09:15:00.000 5.2         15 --------|
I370902P 2015-12-04 09:16:00.000 7.6         16 --------|-> NO (just 2 minutes)
I370902P 2015-12-04 09:17:00.000 4.3         17
                                                Result = 7 min
```

I'm using SQL Server 2008.

Comment: OK good. Shouldn't the answer be 8 minutes? (including rownum=9 with Value=10.1)?

Comment: No, between rownum=9 and rownum=10 2 minutes difference.

Comment: There is nothing in your question about the length of a gap. (You are only talking about intervals *before/after* a gap.) Maybe you should update your question on how to process gaps that are shorter than M minutes.

Comment: @AndriyM I've edited the question. Please look at the example.

Comment: It seems that you don't want the number of minute between 3 and 5 (9:02 to 9:04 = 2 min) but the number of row: 3, 4, 5 => 3. Correct?

Comment: No, I do want the interval between 3 and 5 (9:02, 9:03, 9:04 = 3 min), and between 10 and 13 (9:10, 9:11, 9:12, 9:13 = 4 min)

Answer (score 2):

**Query:**

```
WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT id = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (partition by [Code] order by [Time])
        , [Code]
        , [Time], [Value]
    FROM @data
), grp as(
    SELECT n = c1.id - ROW_NUMBER() OVER (partition by c1.[Code] order by c1.[Time])
        , c1.[Code]
        , c1.[Time]
    FROM cte c1
    LEFT join cte c2 ON c1.Code = c2.Code AND c1.id+1 = c2.id
    WHERE c1.[Value] > @Value
        AND (   NOT (coalesce(DATEDIFF(minute, c1.[Time], c2.[Time]), 1) BETWEEN 2 AND @gap+1)
                OR coalesce(c2.Value, 0) < @Value
            )
)
SELECT [Code], [MIN] = MIN([Time]), [MAX] = MAX([Time]), DIFFERENCE = 1+DATEDIFF(minute, MIN([Time]), MAX([Time]))
FROM grp
GROUP BY [Code], n
HAVING DATEDIFF(minute, MIN([Time]), MAX([Time])) > 1
;
```

- cte give a unique id to each row for each `[Code]` ordered by `[Time]`
- grp does the same thing but only when `[Value] > @Value` and remove this id from the previous id:

  ```
  RowNum  id  ROW_NUMBER  id-ROW_NUMBER   Code        Time                        Value
  3       3   1           2               I370902P    2015-12-04 09:02:00.0000000 6.00
  4       4   2           2               I370902P    2015-12-04 09:03:00.0000000 7.20
  5       5   3           2               I370902P    2015-12-04 09:04:00.0000000 6.40
  9       9   4           5               I370902P    2015-12-04 09:08:00.0000000 10.10
  10      10  5           5               I370902P    2015-12-04 09:10:00.0000000 7.20
  11      11  6           5               I370902P    2015-12-04 09:11:00.0000000 6.70
  ...
  ```
- I then GROUP BY [Code] and n (id - ROW_NUMBER()) in order to get the first and last date of each group and compute DATEDIFF

**Output:**

```
Code        MIN                         MAX                         Diff
I370902P    2015-12-04 09:02:00.0000000 2015-12-04 09:04:00.0000000 3
I370902P    2015-12-04 09:08:00.0000000 2015-12-04 09:13:00.0000000 4
x           2015-12-04 09:02:00.0000000 2015-12-04 09:05:00.0000000 4
```

From this result you only have to `GROUP BY Code` and do the `SUM(diff)`:

```
...
)
SELECT [Code], [Total] = SUM(diff)
FROM (
    SELECT [Code], [MIN] = MIN([Time]), [MAX] = MAX([Time]), diff = 1+DATEDIFF(minute, MIN([Time]), MAX([Time]))
    FROM grp
    GROUP BY [Code], n
    HAVING DATEDIFF(minute, MIN([Time]), MAX([Time])) > 1
) g
GROUP BY [Code]
;
```

**Output:**

```
Code        Total
I370902P    7
xxxxxxxx    4
```

**Data:**

```
declare @Value numeric(10,2) = 5.0;
declare @gap int = 3;

declare @data table 
    ([Code] varchar(8), [Time] datetime2, [Value] numeric(10,2), [RowNum] int)
;

INSERT INTO @data
    ([Code], [Time], [Value], [RowNum])
VALUES
    ('I370902P ', '2015-12-04 09:00:00.000', 5.0, 1),
    ('I370902P ', '2015-12-04 09:01:00.000', 4.4, 2),
    ('I370902P ', '2015-12-04 09:02:00.000', 6.0, 3),
    ('I370902P ', '2015-12-04 09:03:00.000', 7.2, 4),
    ('I370902P ', '2015-12-04 09:04:00.000', 6.4, 5),
    ('I370902P ', '2015-12-04 09:05:00.000', 4.5, 6),
    ('I370902P ', '2015-12-04 09:06:00.000', 4.9, 7),
    ('I370902P ', '2015-12-04 09:07:00.000', 5.0, 8),
    ('I370902P ', '2015-12-04 09:08:00.000', 10.1, 9),
    ('I370902P ', '2015-12-04 09:10:00.000', 7.2, 10),
    ('I370902P ', '2015-12-04 09:11:00.000', 6.7, 11),
    ('I370902P ', '2015-12-04 09:12:00.000', 6.6, 12),
    ('I370902P ', '2015-12-04 09:13:00.000', 7.1, 13),
    ('I370902P ', '2015-12-04 09:14:00.000', 4.1, 14),
    ('I370902P ', '2015-12-04 09:15:00.000', 5.2, 15),
    ('I370902P ', '2015-12-04 09:16:00.000', 7.6, 16),
    ('I370902P ', '2015-12-04 09:17:00.000', 4.3, 17),
    ('xxxxxxxx', '2015-12-04 09:01:00.000', 4.4, 14),
    ('xxxxxxxx', '2015-12-04 09:02:00.000', 6.0, 15),
    ('xxxxxxxx', '2015-12-04 09:03:00.000', 7.2, 16),
    ('xxxxxxxx', '2015-12-04 09:04:00.000', 6.4, 17),
    ('xxxxxxxx', '2015-12-04 09:05:00.000', 6.4, 18),
    ('xxxxxxxx', '2015-12-04 09:06:00.000', 4.5, 19)
;
```

Comment: Row `('I370902P', '2015-12-04 09:08:00.000', 10.1, 9)` shouldn't be in the result.  Only 3, 4, 5 and 10, 11, 12, 13 for `I370902P`. There are 2 minutes between row 9 and row 10 => row 9 dosen't count.

Comment: Yes. Time span shoul be more than `M` minutes (in the example - 3 minutes). If there is a gap, and interval before (or/and after) the gap less than `M` minutes it dosen't count.

Comment: Please look at the example.

Comment: try updated code

Comment: Better, but how can I change minimum interval length (`M`)? In the example `M = 3`

Comment: This is variable @ gap at the end of my answer with you data.

Comment: Great, thanks. I'll test it later, it's almost nighttime here :)

Comment: You have almost everything you need and probably just need to tweak it a little bit of I misunderstood something. You should also take some time and try to understand how it works. You will learn more if you do it yourself. Night as well!

Comment: @Alex does it work as expected?

Comment: Not exacly. I'll post correct version later.